# Pandas.read_csv error tokenizing data

Tags: python, pandas

I am having trouble with Pandas.read_csv

I would like to read this text file **(see below)** When I take this data and copy it into excel > text to columns > delimited by "Space" it gives me the exact output I am looking for.

I have tried a bunch of different ways, I thought that the regEx to account for multiple spaces would do the trick, but I failed to make it work.

I try this code:

```
petrelTxt = pd.read_csv(petrelfile, sep = ' ', header = None)
```

and it gives me the error

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 6 fields in line 2, saw 17
```

When I try changing the "sep = '\s+' " it makes it farther down the file, but still does not work.

```
petrelTxt = pd.read_csv(petrelfile, sep = '\s+', header = None)


CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 3, saw 6
```

This is the original txt file:

```
# WELL TRACE FROM PETREL 
# WELL NAME:              ZZ-0113
# WELL HEAD X-COORDINATE: 9999999.00000000 (m)
# WELL HEAD Y-COORDINATE: 9999999.00000000 (m)
# WELL KB:                159.00000000 (ft)
# WELL TYPE:              OIL
# MD AND TVD ARE REFERENCED (=0) AT KB AND INCREASE DOWNWARDS
# ANGLES ARE GIVEN IN DEGREES
# XYZ TRACE IS GIVEN IN COORDINATE SYSTEM WGS_1924_UTM_Zone_42N
# AZIMUTH REFERENCE TRUE NORTH
# DX DY ARE GIVEN IN GRID NORTH IN m-UNITS
# DEPTH (Z, TVD) GIVEN IN ft-UNITS
#======================================================================================================================================
      MD              X              Y             Z           TVD           DX           DY          AZIM          INCL          DLS
#======================================================================================================================================
 0.0000000000   999999.00000 9999999.0000 159.00000000 0.0000000000 0.0000005192 -0.000000000 1.3487006929 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
 132.00000000   999999.08032 9999999.9116 27.000774702 131.99922530 0.0803153923 -0.088388779 139.08870069 0.3400000000 0.2575757504
 221.00000000   999999.19115 9999999.8017 -61.99775149 220.99775149 0.1911487882 -0.198290891 132.93870069 0.3200000000 0.0456726104
```

Comment: it is not correct CSV file because you have comments. As I remember `read_csv` has option to skip some lines.

Comment: read doc: [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) it has option to skip some lines and to recognize comment - you have to use `comment="#"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `comment="#"`

Example using `io` module to emulate file

```
data = '''# WELL TRACE FROM PETREL 
# WELL NAME:              ZZ-0113
# WELL HEAD X-COORDINATE: 9999999.00000000 (m)
# WELL HEAD Y-COORDINATE: 9999999.00000000 (m)
# WELL KB:                159.00000000 (ft)
# WELL TYPE:              OIL
# MD AND TVD ARE REFERENCED (=0) AT KB AND INCREASE DOWNWARDS
# ANGLES ARE GIVEN IN DEGREES
# XYZ TRACE IS GIVEN IN COORDINATE SYSTEM WGS_1924_UTM_Zone_42N
# AZIMUTH REFERENCE TRUE NORTH
# DX DY ARE GIVEN IN GRID NORTH IN m-UNITS
# DEPTH (Z, TVD) GIVEN IN ft-UNITS
#======================================================================================================================================
      MD              X              Y             Z           TVD           DX           DY          AZIM          INCL          DLS
#======================================================================================================================================
 0.0000000000   999999.00000 9999999.0000 159.00000000 0.0000000000 0.0000005192 -0.000000000 1.3487006929 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
 132.00000000   999999.08032 9999999.9116 27.000774702 131.99922530 0.0803153923 -0.088388779 139.08870069 0.3400000000 0.2575757504
 221.00000000   999999.19115 9999999.8017 -61.99775149 220.99775149 0.1911487882 -0.198290891 132.93870069 0.3200000000 0.0456726104'''

import pandas as pd
import io

f = io.StringIO(data)

df = pd.read_csv(f, comment="#", sep='\s+')

print(df.columns)
print(df.head())
```

Result:

```
Index(['MD', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'TVD', 'DX', 'DY', 'AZIM', 'INCL', 'DLS'], dtype='object')

      MD             X             Y           Z         TVD            DX  \
0    0.0  999999.00000  9.999999e+06  159.000000    0.000000  5.192000e-07   
1  132.0  999999.08032  1.000000e+07   27.000775  131.999225  8.031539e-02   
2  221.0  999999.19115  1.000000e+07  -61.997751  220.997751  1.911488e-01   

         DY        AZIM  INCL       DLS  
0 -0.000000    1.348701  0.00  0.000000  
1 -0.088389  139.088701  0.34  0.257576  
2 -0.198291  132.938701  0.32  0.045673
```

Comment: petrelTxt = pd.read_csv(petrelfile, comment="#", sep='\s+', header=None)                     Hi, thanks, yes I used the comment='#' to and got one output that I need. But I still need to be able to enter the header data and extract information from it..... thanks

Comment: use `names=[]` for custom headers

Comment: Ask new question on SO.