# extracting header data from text file using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I previously asked a question of how to enter this .txt file using pandas.
I was trying with pandas.read_csv

What I found is that I can not read this file using read_csv unless I remove the header data (down to the "#").

The problem is, I need to extract data like, Well Name, Well KB, Well Type... from the header data. Is there a way do do this using Pandas?
Or will I just have to enter it some other way?

my original question was here:

[Pandas.read_csv error tokenizing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328069/pandas-read-csv-error-tokenizing-data/41328270#41328270)

The original text file:

```
# WELL TRACE FROM PETREL 
# WELL NAME:              ZZ-0113
# WELL HEAD X-COORDINATE: 9999999.00000000 (m)
# WELL HEAD Y-COORDINATE: 9999999.00000000 (m)
# WELL KB:                159.00000000 (ft)
# WELL TYPE:              OIL
# MD AND TVD ARE REFERENCED (=0) AT KB AND INCREASE DOWNWARDS
# ANGLES ARE GIVEN IN DEGREES
# XYZ TRACE IS GIVEN IN COORDINATE SYSTEM WGS_1924_UTM_Zone_42N
# AZIMUTH REFERENCE TRUE NORTH
# DX DY ARE GIVEN IN GRID NORTH IN m-UNITS
# DEPTH (Z, TVD) GIVEN IN ft-UNITS
#======================================================================================================================================
      MD              X              Y             Z           TVD           DX           DY          AZIM          INCL          DLS
#======================================================================================================================================
 0.0000000000   999999.00000 9999999.0000 159.00000000 0.0000000000 0.0000005192 -0.000000000 1.3487006929 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
 132.00000000   999999.08032 9999999.9116 27.000774702 131.99922530 0.0803153923 -0.088388779 139.08870069 0.3400000000 0.2575757504
 221.00000000   999999.19115 9999999.8017 -61.99775149 220.99775149 0.1911487882 -0.198290891 132.93870069 0.3200000000 0.0456726104
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the file with the comment indicator as the delimiter and then use pandas `str.extract`

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = """# WELL TRACE FROM PETREL 
# WELL NAME:              ZZ-0113
# WELL HEAD X-COORDINATE: 9999999.00000000 (m)
# WELL HEAD Y-COORDINATE: 9999999.00000000 (m)
# WELL KB:                159.00000000 (ft)
# WELL TYPE:              OIL
# MD AND TVD ARE REFERENCED (=0) AT KB AND INCREASE DOWNWARDS
# ANGLES ARE GIVEN IN DEGREES
# XYZ TRACE IS GIVEN IN COORDINATE SYSTEM WGS_1924_UTM_Zone_42N
# AZIMUTH REFERENCE TRUE NORTH
# DX DY ARE GIVEN IN GRID NORTH IN m-UNITS
# DEPTH (Z, TVD) GIVEN IN ft-UNITS
#======================================================================================================================================
      MD              X              Y             Z           TVD           DX           DY          AZIM          INCL          DLS
#======================================================================================================================================
 0.0000000000   999999.00000 9999999.0000 159.00000000 0.0000000000 0.0000005192 -0.000000000 1.3487006929 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
 132.00000000   999999.08032 9999999.9116 27.000774702 131.99922530 0.0803153923 -0.088388779 139.08870069 0.3400000000 0.2575757504
 221.00000000   999999.19115 9999999.8017 -61.99775149 220.99775149 0.1911487882 -0.198290891 132.93870069 0.3200000000 0.0456726104"""

header_parse = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep='#', skipinitialspace=True, header=None)
hd = header_parse.iloc[:, 1].dropna()

hd.str.extract('\s*(?P<key>[^:]+)\s*:\s*(?P<value>.+)', expand=True).dropna()

                      key                 value
1               WELL NAME               ZZ-0113
2  WELL HEAD X-COORDINATE  9999999.00000000 (m)
3  WELL HEAD Y-COORDINATE  9999999.00000000 (m)
4                 WELL KB     159.00000000 (ft)
5               WELL TYPE                   OIL
```

---

To get rest of data

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), comment='#', delim_whitespace=True)
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its fine. I just will do it this way. But It would be nice to know if I can do it all in Pandas.

```
 fh = open(filePath)
    lst =[]
    for line in fh:
        if line.startswith('# WELL NAME:'):
            line.rstrip()
            lst = line.split()
            wellName = lst[3]
            print (wellname)
            #print (lst)  
        if line.startswith('# WELL KB'):
            line.rstrip()
            lst = line.split()
            kb = lst[3]
            print (kb)
            #print (lst)      
        if line.startswith('# WELL TYPE'):
            line.rstrip()
            lst = line.split()
            wellType = lst[3]
            print (wellType)
            #print (lst)        
        continue
```